# How to run a program from USB?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, autorun

We have a program. We provide this program to client in USB. The Requirement is that when USB is inserted it checks whether the Installer present in USB is already installed on the system or not? If the Installer on the USB is not installed on the system then it Runs the Installer. How can I do this?? Any Suggestion will be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: You mean auto install for first run of the application?

Comment: USB = USB Stick right? Windows?

Comment: @Gens: Yes, thats the requiment

Comment: @CSE: USB = USB stick. You are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal approach is to use autorun.inf
the follow article will describe it :
http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm

The next is up to you, but usually it will be to create some application, which will check your speciffic installation options and run the setup if nessesary.

added :
About your additional wish - to use autoplay without autorun enabled, check the follow article  : http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive-windows-7.htm

maybe you will be interested in : **"Use a U3 smart drive (or similar)."** paragraph inside the article.

Comment: lol .. supercool to drop 2 answers in almost the same time with the same link :D

Comment: Need to flag it for duplicate answer? :)

Comment: :E i would not express an opinion on this, after mine is posted 4 seconds later :D

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev: but autorun in USB does not work in Windows 7. So how can this be solved?

Comment: It does run for sure @Ali Ahmed , but as all autoruns it could be turned on and off. It is a policy.

Comment: @Yordan Yanakiev: Microsoft has disabled USB autorun in Windows 7. But it works for CD/DVD drive.

Comment: check my answer - i have added something which could be usefull.